# Oracle - discrepancy counting tables between TABLES view and TAB_COLUMNS view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm running some top-line stats for our Oracle database, to report a count of the total number of Tables. I'm using some very basic SQL queries against the db views: **TABLES** and **TAB_COLUMNS**

When comparing a count of the number of records in the **DBA_TABLES** view, with a count of the number of distinct Owner/Table_Name combinations in the the **DBA_TAB_COLUMNS**, I've found that there are significantly more tables listed in the **TAB_COLUMNS** view (a total of 12,508, in my case), than in the **TABLES** view (a total of 6,630).

Looking at a data-level sample of the disparities, these 'extra' tables showing in the **TAB_COLUMNS** all appear to contain no rows of data.

Clearly, a chat with my DBA to understand why so many empty tables is my next port of call (could be a number of reasons I'm sure) - but my question is: how come the **TABLES** view apparently excludes these tables, when the **TAB_COLUMNS** view includes them?

Answer (score 0):

There's that useful `dictionary` thing which contains interesting info. For example:

```
SQL> select * from dictionary where table_name in ('USER_TAB_COLUMNS', 'USER_TABLES');

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------
USER_TABLES                    Description of the user's own relational tables
USER_TAB_COLUMNS               Columns of user's tables, views and clusters

SQL>
```

As `user_tab_columns` contains tables **and** views and clusters, I guess that's the reason your queries returned different results. Try to remove what you don't need.

How? One option is to `JOIN` these two. Another is to switch to `USER_OBJECTS` whose `object_type` column says *what is what*.